# Running time of the program

Tags: java

How can I "from program" (I mean before I do "final return" I want to print this time) to find out the time my program was running?

thanks in advance

#### edited

thank You very much for all answers, but I have very short program, is there any other way to find out the time in micro or nano seconds? cause using the method below I receive 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the program starts, you do

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then right before you return from the main method, you do

```
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
System.out.println("Program executed for " + duration + " milliseconds");
```

Comment: I receive 0 :( is there any other way to find out the time in micro or nano seconds?

Comment: Sure. Try [`System.nanoTime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Timing the `main` method, like aioobe suggests, is the simplest way to do it. But it may not work for multithreaded programs, or if the program is terminated by pressing ^C, or by  `System.exit()`, or by an uncaught exception.

If you want to be notified when the program terminates, you can register a listener with [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to use this for profiling purposes? If so, you could use [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to profile you application. In fact, if you're running jdk above 1.6 update 7, you already have it: just type

```
jvisualvm
```

in console and have fun!