# Putting a timer in a program to say how long it took - Java

Tags: java

Just out of interest, it would be nice to know how long my calculation programs run (e.g. Project Euler solutions). Either to see how many milliseconds I can squeeze out of the time by using different solutions, or to see how long it takes to crunch big numbers. Usually such a program ends with a `System.out.println`, printing the answer. How can I put in another `println`, which says "The program took  seconds", or something like that (i.e. increment some variable by 0.001 every millisecond, then print it when the program is done)?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4863701/1065197)

Comment: did you at least try the developer's best friend, google ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get system time in Java without creating a new Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863658/how-to-get-system-time-in-java-without-creating-a-new-date)

Comment: This is a very common need. Basically, `long start=System.nanoTime(); /*do stuff*/ System.out.println("Took " + System.nanoTime()-start);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928513/running-time-of-the-program

Comment: Interesting post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260338/java-benchmarking-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total number of milliseconds easily, using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` call (granularity depends on OS and may not be completely precise). Example:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// portion of code
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time: " + (stop - start) + " ms");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-execution-time.shtml
Here's another complete but different implementation:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-calculate-elapsed-execute-time-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    // do something
    long took = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29):

> **Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds**.
>   This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value
>   returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time
>   (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method
>   provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond
>   accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change.
>   Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately
>   292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time
>   due to numerical overflow.